# Macroscopic particle thought experiment

Tags: special-relativity

I have been daydreaming about the following question and would enjoy any knowledgeable comments. A sphere consisting of 1 µg of iron slams into a concrete wall 10 meters from me traveling at c/2. Ignore atmospheric effects on how it got there. What is the most likely outcome? Some I have considered:

1. I die instantly in the explosion.
2. I die later from the radiation.
3. I hear a bang and see shards go flying but probably survive.
4. I hear a "tink" or "pop" sound. A chip falls from the wall.
5. The particle penetrates the wall (assuming it doesn't hit a rebar) and keeps on going, making little noticeable effect on my environment, apart from a small sound.

Comment: So, in your daydreams, how did you try to answer the question? What calculations or approaches did you try?

Comment: At $c/2$ there are no significant relativistic effects. Maybe compare its kinetic energy with that of a high muzzle velocity bullet?

Comment: More like a cannon shell from a battle ship, at around 1E8 joules.